# Docker - Share GlusterFS mount with another container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, mount, docker-volume, glusterfs

i have created two docker container. One of them mounts glusterfs to /mnt/storage. Now i want to share the gluster mount/folder with the other container.

For this i tried the following docker-compose file:

```
php:
    image: php-image
    hostname: php
    volumes:
      - gluster-volume:/mnt/storage

gluster:
    image: gluster-image
    privileged: true
    volumes:
      - /root/fstab:/etc/fstab
      - gluster-volume:/mnt/storage

volumes:
    gluster-volume:
```

I think the docker volume mount (gluster-volume:/mnt/storage) fails because of the already mounted glusterfs volume on the same path: /mnt/storage. This lead to docker not being able to mount the volume.